# How do I get rid of the labels?

Tags: align, subequations

```
\begin{align}
\alpha\pi\ y_1 + (1-\alpha\ )\pi\ y_2  &\leq\  R[\alpha\ y_1 + (1-\alpha\ )y_2] - C[\alpha\ y_1 + (1-\alpha\ )y_2] \\
&\leq\ (R-C)[\alpha\ y_1 + (1-\alpha\ )y_2] \\
&\leq\pi\ [\alpha\ y_1 + (1-\alpha\ )y_2]
\end{align}
```

[image]
Hi how do I get rid of the (e) (f) (g) at the end of each line?

Comment: Use `align*` instead of `align`. Also, don't use the extra, forced, spacing like `\alpha\pi\ y_1`

Comment: @Werner what does that mean? To use extra forced spacing?  Sorry I literally just started Latex last night so I've pretty much just been learning by copy/pasting code from youtube haha

Comment: Let LaTeX dictate how to space content. So, just `\alpha\pi y_1`, not `\alpha\pi\ y_1`. You're also adding these *control spaces* - ``\ `` before closing parentheses, like this: `(1-a\ )`; don't do that... use `(1-a)`.